# Create a list by aggregation using conditions in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

Hi I'm novice of pyspark.

My data frame looks like this:

```
+--------------------+----------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------+
|            cookieId|sessionSeq|sessionUserSeq|              time  |             keyword  |  code |
+--------------------+----------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------+
|03bdc154-3261-0a9...|         4|             3|  2020-12-12 04:51  |          X-mas tree  |   null|
|03bdc154-3261-0a9...|         4|             4|  2020-12-12 04:52  |          X-mas tree  |   null|
|03bdc154-3261-0a9...|         4|             4|  2020-12-12 04:53  |                null  |   5027|
|03bdc154-3261-0a9...|         4|             7|  2020-12-12 04:54  |          x-mas tree  |   null|
|03bdc154-3261-0a9...|         4|             9|  2020-12-12 04:55  |                bulb  |   null|
|017224a2-2d65-23e...|         8|             2|  2020-12-11 05:04  |          X-mas tree  |   null|
|017224a2-2d65-23e...|         8|             3|  2020-12-11 05:05  |    X-mas decoration  |   null|
|017224a2-2d65-23e...|         8|             3|  2020-12-11 05:06  |                null  |   5028|
|017224a2-2d65-23e...|         8|             8|  2020-12-11 05:07  |    X-mas decoration  |   null|
+--------------------+----------+--------------+--------------------+----------------------+-------+
```

And I want to make a keyword list by grouping the dataframe by 'cookieId' and 'code'. The important point here is that when there is a value in the 'code' column, the 'keyword_list' is made only for times less than the time at that time.

Expected output:

```
+------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|      code  |              cookieId   |                     keyword_list  |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|      5027  |   03bdc154-3261-0a9...  |        [X-mas tree, X-mass tree]  |
|      5028  |   017224a2-2d65-23e...  |   [X-mas tree, X-mas decoration]  |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried a lot but didn't get the desired result. Please help me...!

Answer (score 1):

Use `first` to get the code, and then aggregate using `collect_list`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'code',
    F.first('code', ignorenulls=True).over(
        Window.partitionBy('cookieId')
              .orderBy('time')
              .rowsBetween(0,Window.unboundedFollowing)
    )
).dropna().groupBy(
    'code', 'cookieId'
).agg(
    F.collect_list('keyword').alias('keyword_list')
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----+--------------------+------------------------------+
|code|cookieId            |keyword_list                  |
+----+--------------------+------------------------------+
|5027|03bdc154-3261-0a9...|[X-mas tree, X-mas tree]      |
|5028|017224a2-2d65-23e...|[X-mas tree, X-mas decoration]|
+----+--------------------+------------------------------+
```